# Opentype features in fallback math font (e. g. EB Garamond) in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, opentype

Preamble: In a document I want to use EB Garamond for both text and maths and I don't want to install anything that doesn't come with TeX Live (i. e. no Garamond Math and no URW Garamond).

So here's my typescript thing for that (sorry for the long listing, it is the minimal working example i could make):

```
\definefontfeature
    [eb-garamond-be-normal]
    [default]
    [onum=yes]
\starttypescriptcollection[ebgaramond-be]
    \starttypescript [serif] [ebgaramond-be]
        \loadfontgoodies[ebgaramond]
        \setups[font:fallback:serif]
        \definefontsynonym [Serif] [file:ebgaramond-regular] [features=eb-garamond-be-normal]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [file:ebgaramond-italic] [features=eb-garamond-be-normal]
    \stoptypescript
    \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular.otf] [digitsnormal] [force=yes]
    \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular.otf] [lowercasenormal] [force=yes]
    \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular.otf] [uppercasenormal] [force=yes]
    \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Italic] [lowercasenormal] [offset=lowercaseitalic,force=yes]
    \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Italic] [0x00068] [offset=0x0210E,force=yes] 
    \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Italic] [uppercasenormal] [offset=uppercaseitalic,force=yes]    
    \starttypescript [math] [ebgaramondandbonum] 
        \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [texgyrebonummath] [features={math,mathextra},fallbacks=ebgaramondmathtext]
    \stoptypescript 
    \starttypescript [ebgaramond-be]
        \definetypeface[ebgaramond-be] [rm] [serif] [ebgaramond-be] [default] [designsize=auto]
        \definetypeface[ebgaramond-be] [mm] [math] [ebgaramondandbonum] [default]
    \stoptypescript 
\stoptypescriptcollection
```

It does work:

```
\setupbodyfont[ebgaramond-be]

\starttext
text: {\it abcde123}

math: $abcde123$
\stoptext
```

[image]

but I want lining figures in math mode, instead of oldstyle ones. I tried to create separate feature set with lnum=yes,onum=no using \definefontfeature and add it alongside with {math,mathextra} to the main math font with no luck. Even worse: when I make lnum=yes for the main text font, it affects only text mode, leaving oldstyle figures in math mode:

[image]

Is it possible to set opentype features (like lnum, for example) to fallback fonts? Or, maybe, there are some other solutions?

**Upd:**

In the comments Metafox posted a solution. First there should be a fontfeature that does not rely on `default`

```
\definefontfeature [EBGM] [lnum=yes]
```

and then this feature can be referenced using `*` after file name in the fallback definition:

```
\definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular.otf*EBGM] [digitsnormal] [force=yes]
```

Comment: To apply features to the fallback font you have to first create a synonym for the font file (e.g. `\definefontsynonym [EBGaramond-Regular] [file:ebgaramond12regular] [features=...]`) where you can apply the features and then load the font synonym in your fallback definition (e.g. `\definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [EBGaramond-Regular] [...] [...]`).

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that either, like this:

\definefontfeature
 [eb-garamond-be-math]
 [default]
 [lnum=yes,onum=no]
...
 \definefontsynonym [EBGM] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular.otf] [features=eb-garamond-be-math]
 \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [EBGM] [digitsnormal] [force=yes]

and it doesn't produce digits at all, but '?' instead. For some reason \definefontfallback doesn't seem to understand font synonyms.

Comment: There is a second method where you set the features with the font file, the font and the features in this case are separated with a `*`.  The fallback for the digits in your example should be like this: `\definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:ebgaramond12regular*eb-garamond-be-normal] [...] [...]`.

Comment: I didn't try it before, but it doesn't seem to work. With `\definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:ebgaramond12regular*eb-garamond-be-math] [digitsnormal] [force=yes]` digits do appear, but they are oldstyle, no matter what features are set in `eb-garamond-be-math`

Comment: You have to use `base` mode for the features of your math fallbacks, e.g. `\definefontfeature [ebgaramondmath] [lnum=yes]` and apply this feature set to your font files. The `default` features use `node` mode which doesn’t work in math mode.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much! It does work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Features in math mode can only be changed when you’re in `base` mode but in your example you create a new feature based on the `default` set which uses `node` mode.

The easiest way to achieve this by creating a new feature without an mode settings because (ligatures etc. aren needed for symbols in math mode):

```
\definefontfeature [ebgaramond-math] [lnum=yes]
```

Another problem in your example is that you never apply the feature to your fallback font for the digits, to do this can either apply the feature with the font file in the `\definefontfallback` command, e.g.

```
\starttypescript [math] [ebgaramondandbonum]
  \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular*ebgaramond-math] [digitsnormal] [force=yes]
  \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [texgyrebonummath] [features={math,mathextra},fallbacks=ebgaramondmathtext]
\stoptypescript
```

or you use a two-step-method where you create a font synonym where you can use the third argument to set the features and load afterwards the synonym in the font fallback, e.g.

```
\starttypescript [math] [ebgaramondandbonum]
  \definefontsynonym  [EBGaramondFallback-Regular] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular] [features=ebgaramond-math]
  \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [EBGaramondFallback-Regular] [digitsnormal] [force=yes]
  \definefontsynonym  [MathRoman] [texgyrebonummath] [features={math,mathextra},fallbacks=ebgaramondmathtext]
\stoptypescript
```

The complete code to replace the digits from the math font with digits from EB Garamond would look like this:

```
\definefontfeature [ebgaramond-text] [default] [lnum=yes]
\definefontfeature [ebgaramond-math]           [lnum=yes]

\starttypescript [serif] [ebgaramond-be]
  \setups[font:fallback:serif]
  \loadfontgoodies[ebgaramond]
  \definefontsynonym [Serif]       [file:ebgaramond-regular] [features=ebgaramond-text]
  \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [file:ebgaramond-italic]  [features=ebgaramond-text]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [math] [ebgaramondandbonum]
  \definefontsynonym  [EBGaramondFallback-Regular] [file:EBGaramond12-Regular] [features=ebgaramond-math]
  \definefontfallback [ebgaramondmathtext] [EBGaramondFallback-Regular] [digitsnormal] [force=yes]
  \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [texgyrebonummath] [features={math,mathextra},fallbacks=ebgaramondmathtext]
\stoptypescript 

\starttypescript [ebgaramond-be]
  \definetypeface[ebgaramond-be] [rm] [serif] [ebgaramond-be] [default] [designsize=auto]
  \definetypeface[ebgaramond-be] [mm] [math] [ebgaramondandbonum] [default]
\stoptypescript 

\setupbodyfont[ebgaramond-be]

\starttext

text: {\it abcde123}

math: $abcde123$

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again. The general idea definitely works, but your example doesn't actually produce text in Garamond EB (looking at the screenshot you provided it seems more like Bonum all over the place and i've tested it, with similar results).

Comment: @SergeySlyusarev There was a `-` missing in the names of the text font which is required for the names in the goodies file.